# Subset only those rows whose intervals does not fall within another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, overlapping-matches

How can i compare two data frames (test and control) of unequal length,  and remove the row from test based on three criteria, i) if the  test$chr == control$chr
ii) test$start and test$end lies with in the range of control$start and control$end
iii) test$CNA and control$CNA are same.

```
    test = 
        R_level  logp   chr start   end     CNA    Gene
        2     7.079     11  1159    1360    gain   Recl,Bcl
        11    2.4       12  6335    6345    loss   Pekg
        3     19        13  7180    7229    loss   Sox1

control =

  R_level    logp   chr  start  end     CNA    Gene
        2     5.9     11  1100  1400    gain   Recl,Bcl 
        2     3.46    11  1002  1345    gain    Trp1
        2     6.4     12  6705  6845    gain    Pekg
        4     7       13  6480  8129    loss    Sox1
```

The result should look something like this

```
result =
     R_level     logp   chr start   end     CNA     Gene
          11      2.4    12  6335   6345    loss   Pekg
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Further specify your question please.

Comment: On line 2, you mean `data1[,4] > data2[,5] &`  (not daat2) right?

Comment: Sorry for the typos. its actually data2[,5].i want to remove the rows which satisfy the above mentioned following criterias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `foverlaps()` from `data.table`.

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.4+
dt1 <- as.data.table(test)
dt2 <- as.data.table(control)
setkey(dt2, chr, CNA, start, end)

olaps = foverlaps(dt1, dt2, nomatch=0L, which=TRUE, type="within")
#    xid yid
# 1:   1   2
# 2:   3   4

dt1[!olaps$xid]
#    R_level logp chr start  end  CNA Gene
# 1:      11  2.4  12  6335 6345 loss Pekg
```

Read `?foverlaps` and see the examples section for more info.

Alternatively, you can also use `GenomicRanges` package. However, you might have to filter based on `CNA` after merging by overlapping regions (AFAICT).

Answer (score 0):

When you say "exclude the variable", I assume you mean you want to remove the rows that satisfies those criteria.

If so, you are nearly there. The following should work:

```
exclude_bool <- data1[,3] == data2[,3] &
data1[,4] > data2[,5] &
data1[,5] < data2[,4] &
data1[,6] == data2[,6] 

data1 <- data1[!exclude_bool , ]
```

Comment: Thank you decoder..But it seems the length of both data frames are not same. Warning messages:
1: In data1[, 3] == data2[, 3] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In data1[, 4] > data2[, 5] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In data1[, 5] < data2[, 4] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In daat1[, 6] == daat2[, 6] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: If the length is not the same, the comparisons don't make sense. What do you mean when you say `data1[,3]==data2[,3]`? Since in R, this syntax is comparing the values element-wise. The same is true for `data1[,4] > data2[,5]`: how do you want the comparisons to happen? Should the max value of `data1[,5]` be larger than that of `data2[,4]`?

Comment: data1 is test and data 2 is control. I want to filter the row in test if a) data1[,3] is equal to data2[,3]  b)if  start and end of test (data1) is with in the range of start and end of control (data2) c) and if data1[,6] is also equal to data2[,6].

Comment: Then they will still need to have the same number of rows. I think you will have to update your question to reflect exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: But what if the number of rows are not equal. how can we force R to perform the comparison? In my case the no. of rows in test and control is not equal.

Comment: You can't force R to compare two objects of different lengths, just like you can't force R to compare apples with pears. You have to tell it how to compare the objects. If you update your question with an example of how you want to compare, perhaps we can use a different function.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `data1[,6]` is equal to `data2[,6]`. These are two vectors of different length. How do you compare them? That is, how would you compare `c(1,2,3)` with `c(3,2)`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Sixth column of control and test contains two vectors, gain and loss. If the values in both test and control are similar  then remove the row and if test contain gain and control contains loss or vice versa print.