# How to filter data.frame which has more than n number of entries in a column

Tags: r

How can i  remove row from the dataset which have more than n number of genes.

```
data1 <- Re_leve logp   chr  start  end     CNA     Genes 
             1  1.5     1   739400  756200  gain    Trp1,Eggier 
             1  8.3     1   127730  128210  gain    Zranb3,R3hdm1,.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
library(stringr)
n <- 1
df1[!str_count(df1$Genes, ',')+1 >n,]
```

Comment: @beginner Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @beginner Are you not asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109327/subset-only-those-rows-whose-intervals-does-not-fall-within-another-data-frame

Comment: @beginner Have you tried the solutions in the link.  Also, this question and the description is completely different from your follow up question.

Comment: Here i want to remove the overlaps within the same dataset,not comparison

Comment: I can post it as a different question

Comment: @beginner That will be better and when you post, please include the link and mention why it didn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#dummy data
data1 <- data.frame(x=1:3,
                    Gene=c("asdf,asdf,ee,d","asdf","dfd,sdf"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#minimum number of genes
n <- 1

#subset
data1[sapply(data1$Gene,function(i)length(unlist(strsplit(i,",")))) > n, ]

#   x           Gene
# 1 1 asdf,asdf,ee,d
# 3 3        dfd,sdf
```